# Kendo UI (ASP.NET) scheduler control scrolling does not work in iPhone iOS V.13

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

We use the KendoUI Scheduler control in our ASP.NET MVC project. Currently we're facing an issue where we are unable to do scrolling in the control when the site is viewed in an IPhone (IOS V.13)